# Adding numpy 3D array across one dimension

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with following shape:

```
(365L, 280L, 300L)
```

I want to sum up the array across the first dimension (365), so that I get 365 values as result.

I can do `np.sum()`, but how to specify which axis?

--EDIT:

The answer should have shape: (365,)

Comment: numpy.sum takes an axis argument, so `np.sum(X,axis=(1,2))` should do the trick.

Comment: The answer should have shape: (365,), using axis=0, I get shape (280, 300)

Answer (score 3):

## NumPy version >= 1.7

[`np.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) allows the use of a `tuple of integer` as `axis` argument to calculate the sum along multiple axis at once:

```
import numpy as np
arr = ... # somearray

np.sum(arr, axis=(1, 2)) # along axis 1 and 2 (remember the first axis has index 0)
np.sum(arr, axis=(2, 1)) # the order doesn't matter
```

Or directly use the `sum` method of the array:

```
arr.sum(axis=(1, 2))
```

The latter only works if `arr` is already a numpy array. `np.sum` works even if your `arr` is a python-`list`.

## NumPy version < 1.7:

The option to use a tuple as `axis` argument wasn't implemented yet but you could always nest multiple `np.sum` or `.sum` calls:

```
np.sum(np.sum(arr, axis=1), axis=1)  # Nested sums
arr.sum(axis=2).sum(axis=1)          # identical but more "sequential" than "nested"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.random.random((365L, 280L, 300L)) # just an example

s = numpy.sum(a, axis=(1,2))

print s.shape

> (365,)
```